# How to retrieve a view using findViewWithTag from root view?

Tags: android

I have a complicated dynamic view with multiple child and parents.
I'm setting tags to the views using settags. 
One EditText view has tag value "1".

When I try to retrieve the View using findViewWithTag, I'm getting null response.

Below is my code.

```
//Set Tag 
EditText editText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);
            editText.setPadding(0,eight,0,eight);
            editText.setTag("1");

// Get Tag
EditText et =(EditText)home.getRootView().findViewWithTag("1");
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you `setTag()`?

Comment: @VeneetReddy posted

Comment: is that edittext is inside a for loop??

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the below method. As I had a unique ID for each view, I took the view in the first position in the ArrayList for each Tag.

```
 private static ArrayList<View> getViewsByTag(ViewGroup root, String tag){
    ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
    final int childCount = root.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = root.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            views.addAll(getViewsByTag((ViewGroup) child, tag));
        }

        final Object tagObj = child.getTag();
        if (tagObj != null && tagObj.equals(tag)) {
            views.add(child);
        }

    }
    return views;
}
```